# NavMesh - Changing Mesh by Jumping upwards

Tags: unity, ai, navmesh

I have been playing around with the NavMesh and I have seen that there are different situations where an agent has to change meshes.

## When it works:

Everything seems to work alright with links, if I try to make the agent **jump from a mesh to another one**, tweaking the "Jump distance" paramenter

[image]

Another scenario is when the agent needs to **fall to another mesh** to reach the target. This one also works, when I tweak the "Drop height" parameter.

[image]

## When it does NOT work

But there are 2 different scenarios, where the agent cant reach the target. The first one is when the agent must **jump upwards** instead of dropping.

[image]

And the other scenario is when the agent needs to **fall to another mesh that is not directly below** the one he is standing on.

[image]

How could I do so that the agent jumps either to move upwards, or to land in a lower mesh?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to use `OffMeshLink` component to jump upwards. I did not try the last scenario you mention, but it should work too. Put the start link at the bottom, end link at the top and tick bi-directional.

`OffMeshLink` component allows you to incorporate navigation shortcuts which cannot be represented using a walkable surface. For example, jumping over a ditch or a fence, or opening a door before walking through it, can all be described as Off-mesh links. [Here's the documentation for it.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-OffMeshLink.html)